# JavaScript for loop goes too many times.

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Can someone tell me why the value of 'i' in this code prints out the number 4? the loop only goes to 3, however it will print 'i = 4' inside of the menu_feedback div.

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
    $('#file_button'+i).hover(function (){
        $('#menu_feedback').html('i = '+i+'<br/>');
    }, function(){
        $('#menu_feedback').html('');
    });
}
```

.

```
<button type="button" id="file_button1">Door 1</button>
<button type="button" id="file_button2">Door 2</button>
<button type="button" id="file_button3">Door 3</button>

<div id="menu_feedback"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, probably the second most asked JavaScript question....where is the dupe...

Comment: @epascarello what's the first ?

Comment: @dystroy That would be Asynchronous Ajax, why is it returning undefined. Seems like that one is asked 5 times a day.

Comment: So less than the times I seem to see the (perfectly valid and legitimate) answer given there by kolink ;)

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the world of closures.

Use this:

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        // the code that depends on i
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic JavaScript problem.  It's because the variable `i` in your `hover` function is the same variable from the loop.  So, when the loop ends, `i` is 4, so it's 4 in the function.

Try something like this:

```
var hoverFunc = function(i){
    return function(){
        $('#menu_feedback').html('i = '+i+'<br/>');
    };
};
for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
    $('#file_button'+i).hover(hoverFunc(i), function(){
        $('#menu_feedback').html('');
    });
}
```

`hoverFunc` is a closure.  It returns a function that "closes" around the value of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for more information about the problem you are facing.

However, with jQuery event handlers, there is an other way to solve this, by passing the index as event data:

```
for(i=1; i<=3; i++){
    $('#file_button'+i).mouseenter({index: i}, function(event){
        $('#menu_feedback').html('i = '+ event.data.index + '<br/>');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('#menu_feedback').html('');
    });
}
```

Comment: Woah.  Didn't know you could pass an object to jQuery events like that.  Neat.